# Are there any boats from Île Sainte-Marguerite to Île Saint-Honorat?

Tags: france, islands, french-riviera, cannes

I am interested in going to the two Lerins Islands, opposite Cannes, France.

I know that there are boats from the mainland to either island. However, is there any boat that runs between the two islands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four different companies that visit the two islands on a regular schedule, but unfortunately, none of them visits both islands; 3 of them depart from the Quai Laubeuf. Your only chance would be to charter your own boat and to book a round trip. Since both trips are relatively cheap by ferry (around 15 EUR) and short (15 mins), it might turn out to be very expensive for you having someone to wait for you during the 2-3 hours it takes to visit each island.

The only thing I can imagine is that you try to hail one of the private boats when they arrive at your first destination while dropping off someone and ask them to transfer you to the other island.